# Dictionary comprehension to create dictionary of even numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary-comprehension

I want to create a dictionary of even numbers with the keys being consecutive integers using dictionary comprehension

*The output should be:*

```
{1:2,2:4,3:6,4:8}
```

I used 2 lines of code ie one line being the list comprehension to get the even numbers and the second being the dictionary comprehension to get the desired output.

*The code i used is as follows:*

```
evens=[number for number in range(1,10) if number%2==0]
even_dict={k:evens[k-1] for k in range(1,len(evens)+1)}
```

My question is instead of using 2 lines of code, can we use a single line of code which involves only dictionary comprehension to get the desired output?

Answer (score 1):

According to what is your desired output, you can simply do:

```
d = {x: 2*x for x in range(1, 5)}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it now, you have to define `evens` before since you are using it in two places in the dict comprehension: To iterate the indices, and to get the actual element. Generally, whenever you need both the index and the element, you can use `enumerate` instead, possible with `start` parameter if you want to offset the index:

```
even_dict = {i: x for i, x in enumerate(evens, start=1)}
```

Now you only need `evens` once, and thus you could "inline" it into the dict comprehension:

```
even_dict = {i: x for i, x in enumerate([number for number in range(1,10) if number%2==0], start=1)}
```

But you do not need that inner list comprehension at all; to get the even numbers, you could just use `range` with `step` parameter:

```
even_dict = {i: x for i, x in enumerate(range(2, 10, 2), start=1)}
```

And, finally, in this particular case, you would not even need that, either, as you can just multiply the key with two to get the value, as shown in [@olinox's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56114150/1639625).